# WooCommerce, how to set different 'number of products per page' to different category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I build my website by Wordpress and using WooCommerce to show products.

I created two different category layout templates for my categories. And I know how to change number of products per page from http://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/

But if I want to display 20 products per page in category_1 and 40 products per page in category_2, how to do that then?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your functions.php

```
function products_per_page_category( $count ) {

    if( is_product_category( "category_1 " ) ) :
        return 40;
    elseif( is_product_category( "category_2 " ) ) :
        return 20;
    else :
        return $count;
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'products_per_page_category', 20 );
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I didn't have to change anything programming wise.

In the normal WP Admin, go

**Settings > Reading > "Blog pages show at most"**

Set that setting to however many products you want to show per page.

Of course, this will impact both your blog's total number of posts in the list, and your store, because products are simply a custom post type, and this affects all default "posts" page lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three other options.

1. Change your **Reading Settings**.

Woocommerce products are simply posts, and products archives are using the reading settings to determine the number of posts per page. Go to **Settings** > **Reading** in the admin panel.

1. Try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-archive-customiser/)

It allows you to change the number of products and columns per page in product archives by selecting your settings in an admin panel options menu.

1. [Try this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/)

It allows you to configure the same, but presents the selection to a site visitor on the front end, saves their selection in a cookie and applies the setting site-wide.

These plugins will allow you to write a similar conditional to set the default products per page, and optionally give your site-user the choice of # of products per page.

Answer (score 0):

In many woocommerce themes there are product carousel available . Check them before doing any vague tricks. You can setup category in that product carousel and also there comes an option with it to change the number of items to be shown. Also the best thing about carousel is that it doesnt loads the page again if you want to show more products it comes up with a slider to see all products.